# How can I get the spring-boot-actuator metrics data in code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I know that we can use web url to get the metrics.
However, I want to get the data that created by spring-boot-actuator in my code.
I want to program to get the metrics and then publish to other destination in my spring-boot project.
The micormeter-registy-xxxx can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish the data to another destination, you need to implement your own registry. Take a look at other registries to see how to do it.

If you want to push metrics to logs or use the data as string, you can take a look at [`LogingMeterRegistry`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/e5d2442fc6c6a656e86e4ae0534f8da3e93342ac/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/logging/LoggingMeterRegistry.java) and [`SimpleMeterRegistry#getMetersAsString`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/e5d2442fc6c6a656e86e4ae0534f8da3e93342ac/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/simple/SimpleMeterRegistry.java#L178).